# SELECT GROUP BY clause incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by

Issue is receiving MySQL error when executing the following MySQL query (via PHP):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(USER), ID, IS_VALID FROM `LOGIN_LOG`
WHERE `SETUP` = 'setup1'
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY `time` desc;
```

To obtain results like this:

```
+--------+----+----------+
| USER   | ID | IS_VALID |
+--------+----+----------+
| JSMITH | 10 |    1     |
+--------+----+----------+
| DADAMS | 15 |    1     |
+--------+----+----------+
```

MySQL Error:

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 
>   'mercedes_sentry.PS_LOGIN_LOG.TIME' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY 
>   clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I know I could change SQL Mode, but do not see this solution as ideal as the results may be unpredictable, and not always accurate. I'd prefer to fix the query. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The query can be fixed only if you use ID and IS_VALID in the GROUP BY clause, or aggregate on them (which I don't think that you want). Also DISTINCT is useless since you `GROUP BY USER`

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with the `GROUP BY` and the `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @slaakso You are right, changed to SELECT USER, ID, IS_VALID FROM `LOGIN_LOG` WHERE `SETUP` = 'setup1' GROUP BY USER ORDER BY `time` desc; But how address the initial issue.

Comment: @forpas You are right too, and also a thanks for heads up regarding DISTINCT. Sorry, should have mentioned you first.

Comment: You still did not answer what you are trying to do with `GROUP BY`. A `GROUP BY` is used with aggregate functions (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `COUNT` etc.) which you do not have.  If a user has multiple rows in `LOGIN_LOG`, which of those do you want to show?

Comment: @slaakso Simply, compile a list of USERs in the LOGIN_LOG table. Any given USER can have multiple rows, but I want just a list of one unique USER per line.

Comment: You want one row per user. If the rows for one user have different data (for example one has IS_VALID=0 and the another has IS_VALID=1), which one of those do you want to show?